# Execute javascript after page has loaded and scrolled to hashtag anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that contains a bunch of parts, all of which can be scrolled to using hashtag links (e.g. `www.marie-charlot.be/#weiss`).

I know how to execute javascript functions that trigger after the page loads (using `$(document).ready`, but these generally trigger before the page is scrolled down to the correct part (the `#weiss` anchor).

how do I execute scripts *after* the scrolling?

Comment: Have a look at the [Scrollspy plugin](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy)

Comment: Scrollspy should help you out there. It can execute functions depending on what part of the page the user has scrolled to. Waypoints looks very similar.

Comment: your plugin has callback option...use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the JQuery plugin [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) for this.

**Example:**

```
$('.entry').waypoint(function() {
   alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
});
```

Comment: I'm already using Jquery waypoints to change the state of the page (e.g. determine which set I'm currently in). The point is that I want to wait for the page to scroll down so that this change of state can be used in the function I want to call.

Comment: it actually worked by extracting the hashtag id and adding a single call function to the anchor with that id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var anchorTop = $('#my-anchor').offset().top;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if($(document).scrollTop() >= anchorTop)
            yourFunctionHere();
    });
});
```